# how to clear redux cart in my react native code

Tags: react-native, react-redux

My Code will not remove contents that have been added into the cart on the cart page ,im a beginner i hope you can assist me on this and if you can may you explain how the system really works in lamens terms .

This is my crat page code :

```
render() {

      console.log(this.props.cartItems)
//    const cartItems = this.props.cartItems;
      const cartLength = this.props.cartItems.length;
      const total = this.props.cartItems.price;

      let sum = this.props.cartItems.reduce((a,b)=> a +(b.price || 0),0);

      return (

        <MainContainer>
          <View style={{flex:3, backgroundColor:"#faf6f5", borderRadius:12}}>
            <ScrollView>

            {this.props.cartItems.map((item, index) => {
                return (


                      <Menu key={index} style={{ padding: 0.5 }}>

                        <MenuImage source={item.image}/>
                          <MenuInfor>
                            <Text dark bold>{item.name}</Text>
                            <Text dark small>{item.info}</Text>
                            <Text dark bold>${item.price}</Text>
                          </MenuInfor>
                          <TouchableOpacity
                            onPress={this.props.removeItem.id}
                          
                            style={{alignItems: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}
                          >
                            <AntDesign name="minuscircleo" size={30} color="#000" />
                          </TouchableOpacity>
                          </Menu>
                )
            })}
            </ScrollView>
```

const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
return {
cartItems: state
}
}

```
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
      removeItem: (product) => dispatch({ type: 'REMOVE_FROM_CART', payload: product },
      
      alert("Item Removed from Cart!!") 
      
      ),

      onClearCart: (product) => dispatch({type: 'CLEAR_CART', payload: product } )

    }
}




export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)
(Cart);
```

This is my Reducer code below :

```
const initialState = {
  products: [],
};
const ShoppinReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    case ADD_TO_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map(product =>
          product.id === action.id ? {...product, selected: true} : product,
        ),
      };
    case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map(product =>
          product.id === action.id
            ? {...product, selected: false, quantity: 1}
            : product,
        ),
      };
    case ADD_QUANTITY:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map(product =>
          product.id === action.id
            ? {...product, quantity: product.quantity + 1}
            : product,
        ),
      };
    case SUB_QUANTITY:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map(product =>
          product.id === action.id
            ? {
                ...product,
                quantity: product.quantity !== 1 ? product.quantity - 1 : 1,
              }
            : product,
        ),
      };
    case EMPTY_CART:
      return {
        ...state,
        products: state.products.map(product =>
          product.selected
            ? {...product, selected: false, quantity: 1}
            : product,
        ),
      };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};
export {ShoppinReducer};
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should update

1. mapDispatchToProps

```js
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    removeItem: (cartItemId) =>
      dispatch({
        type: 'REMOVE_FROM_CART',
        payload: { cartItemId },
      }),
    // ...
  };
};
```

2. also `onPress` handler

```js
onPress={() => this.props.removeItem(item.id)}
```

3. and reducer case

```js
  case REMOVE_FROM_CART:
    return {
      ...state,
      products: state.products.filter((product) => product.id !== action.payload.cartItemId),
    };
```

Comment: that did work i have another same question i posted with updated code in the following link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68397043/how-to-remove-an-item-from-cart-in-react-native-using-redux