# how to remove an item from cart in react native using redux

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

i am having challenges when i remove items from my cart the cart is not removing the item from the cart but instead adding a blank item

<

This is the cart Screen

```
ScrollView>
       {this.props.cartItems.map((item, index) => {
          return (
            <Menu key={index} style={{ padding: 0.5 }}>
              <MenuImage source={item.image}/>
                <MenuInfor>
                  <Text dark bold>{item.name}</Text>
                  <Text dark small>{item.info}</Text>
                  <Text dark bold>${item.price}</Text>
                </MenuInfor>
              <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={() => this.props.removeItem(item.id)}            
                style={{alignItems: 'flex-end', justifyContent: 'flex-end', alignSelf: 'flex-end'}}
              >
                <AntDesign name="minuscircleo" size={30} color="#000" />
              </TouchableOpacity>
            </Menu>
                )
            })}
      </ScrollView>
```

The following is my action.js file

```
 const addToCart = (id, count) => (
  {
    type: 'ADD_TO_CART',
    payload:{
      id,
      count,
    }

  }
);

// removeFromCart
const removeFromCart = (id) => (
  {
    type: 'REMOVE_FROM_CART',
    id,
    count,
  }
);
```

the following is my reducer.js file

```
const cartItems = (state = [], action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'ADD_TO_CART':{
            return [...state, action.payload ]            
          }
        case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':    
             
        return [...state, state.filter(cartItem => cartItem.id !== action.payload.id)]
        
        case 'CLEAR_CART':
        return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: ['']
        }
      }
    return state
}
export default cartItems
```

Comment: Could you please share the initial state of the reducer?

Comment: I believe your return statement in the 'REMOVE_FROM_CART' portion of the reducer is slightly incorrect. I'm not sure how to exactly solve your problem, but your other return statements are returning objects, while your remove cart one is returning an array. You might try something like this: `return { ...state, cartItems: state.cartItems.filter(....)};`

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code you provided....I think this is the only mistake in your code.

```
case 'REMOVE_FROM_CART':   
   return {
        ...state,
        cartItems: state.cartItems.filter((cartItem) => cartItem.id != 
        action.payload.id)
      };
```

Comment: i have applied that code but it says undefined is not an object (evaluating ''state.cartitems.filter) this code appears after i hit the remove item button in the cart

Comment: Could you please share your initial state of the reducer. I assumed that you have a cartItems array in your state....if your state is the array that you are updating then `state.cartItems.filter` should be replaced by `state.filter`.